# How can I assign non-numerical Ids to list elements in Python?

Tags: python, string

I have a list of Strings and I want to assign to all of them a unique suffix as an Id as it follows:

Let's asume that the list is **["str1", "str2", "str3"]**, I want to insert the Ids like this: **["str1-a", "str2-b", "str3-c"]**.

Is there any way of assigning these ids iteratively like:

```
id = a
for each element in the list:
    add the id to the string
    increment the id # from a to b, from b to c etc.
```

instead of getting each element in order and doing it three times?

In my case I know that there are less than 26 elements so the fact that the alphabet has only 26 letters is not a problem.

Thanks!!

Comment: What should happen if there are more than 26 strings?

Comment: In my case I know that there will be no more than 26 strings. I supose that In a case like that I would have to combine somehow these characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a constant in the `string` module which has all the letters in a string, like `'abcdefg...'`. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase).

```py
from string import ascii_lowercase
new_list = []
for letter, element in zip(ascii_lowercase, old_list):
    new_list.append(element + '-' + letter)
```

Or, using a list comprehension:

```py
new_list = [element + '-' + letter for letter, element in zip(ascii_lowercase, old_list)]
```